# How to list-initialize an initializer_list from another initializer_list

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, initializer-list, list-initialization, direct-initialization

When I'm trying to compile the following code, the compiler complains:

```
int main(void)
{
  std::initializer_list<int> lst1{};
  std::initializer_list<int> lst2{lst1}; // error
}
```

The compiler (gcc) gives me the following error:

```
 error: could not convert '{lst1}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::initializer_list<int>'
```

But when I tried to use direct-initialization the program compiles fines:

```
 std::initializer_list<int> lst2(lst1); // OK
```

Why this is well-formed? Why the compiler rejects the list-initialization and allows direct-initialization? Is there's a rule from the standard for that?

Aslo, Is the following code is well-formed? I mean, Can I do this:

```
int main(void)
{
  std::initializer_list<int> lst1{};
  std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>> lst2{lst1}; //OK
}
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you can't list-initialize a `std::initializer_list<int>` from the same type is that there is a special rule for list-initialization of a `std::initializer_list<E>`, which takes precedence over the other rules for list-initialization. The rule is [[dcl.init.list]/3.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.6):

> Otherwise, if `T` is a specialization of `std​::​initializer_­list<E>`, the object is constructed as described below.

"Below" can only be referring to [dcl.init.list]/5 (and /6):

> An object of type `std​::​initializer_­list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation generated and materialized ([conv.rval]) a prvalue of type "array of *N* `const E`", where *N* is the number of elements in the initializer list. Each element of that array is copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer list, and the `std​::​initializer_­list<E>` object is constructed to refer to that array. [...]

That means that when list-initializating `std::initializer_list<E>`, the only possible interpretation of such an initialization is that the elements of the braced-init-list are used to initialize the elements of the `std::initialize_list<E>` object. Even though this is ill-formed, the compiler cannot go back and try the next rule even though it might be well-formed (*i.e.*, [dcl.init.list]/3.7, which can select a copy constructor).

[dcl.init.list]/5 also governs the meaning of the other initialization you ask about:

```
std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>> lst2{lst1};
```

It is well-formed with an obvious meaning.